# Вложенные теги шаблонов django

Tags: python, django

Я включаю в шаблон другой шаблон задавая набор переменных, в том числе и ссылку (action):

```
{% include "ssn/block_form_as_table.html" with form=form action='ssn:hoster_server_create_action' submit_title='Create a server' %}
```

Теперь мне потребовалось передать в качестве переменной ссылку с параметром. Каким образом я могу сделать следующее:

```
{% include "ssn/block_form_as_table.html" with form=form action={% url 'ssn:hoster_server_edit_action' server_id=server.id %} submit_title='Save a server' %}
```

С той же проблемой я сталкиваюсь, когда хочу в `submit_title` передать не просто текст `Create a server`, а `{% trans 'Create a server' %}`.

В общем, каким образом я могу в параметрах тегов использовать результат выполнения других тегов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
{% url 'ssn:hoster_server_edit_action' server_id=server.id as some_url %}
{% trans 'Create a server' as some_trans %}
{% include "ssn/block_form_as_table.html" with form=form action=some_url submit_title=some_trans %}
```

Ну или вообще передать переменные через вьюху и использовать их в подключаемом шаблоне.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это то, что нужно. Я и не знал о возможности сохранять результат работы тега в переменную таким образом.

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей лучше использовать [templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/), туда тоже можете легко параметры передать и возможностей больше для работы с шаблоном.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Мне бы всего лишь подключить шаблон с контекстом в виде пары переменных. Описывать теги - из пушки по воробьям.